# Add Glyphicon to Silverstripe UserDefinedForm

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, silverstripe, glyphicons

I am bulding a site using the Silverstripe CMS. My client has placed a requirement that the forms should be styled using Glyphicons like the one [here](http://embed.plnkr.co/5D8fv5o5egpKpYz509O3/preview).

I am using UserForms module for the forms. But I am having hard time altering the structure of the form.
Also found a discussion regarding this in the [Silverstripe forum](http://www.silverstripe.org/community/forums/all-other-modules/show/10604/).

Can this in any way be achieved using UserDefinedForms module?

Answer (score 1):

You should try to stick to altering the css than amending the form output as it gets really complicated due it being a dynamic generator. And by quickly looking you probably should be able to that with some css refactoring mostly.

Your sample seemed to include the bootstrap library so this might help you https://github.com/unclecheese/silverstripe-bootstrap-forms as it has an extension to the userdefined form as it outputs the forms with the necessary wrappers for bootstap and give you different choices on what to target with css.